# How would I prepare this narrow clearance wall for drywall?

Tags: drywall, basement, framing

I’m unsure how to set up this wall for the drywallers. I don’t have much clearance from the door opening to the concrete. There is also a layer of reflective insulation directly on the concrete.

First thought is using powder actuated nailer to attach 3 x 1 strapping and just using adhesive to hold the drywall.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sounds good but I would also suggest topping off with some drywall screws.

Comment: Is that reflective insulation merely a radiant barrier, or is it acting as a vapor barrier as well? What's on the other side of the concrete?

Comment: i believe is acting as both a vapor and radiant barrier. but am unsure of the intent.